# Random background color on anchor only gets first anchor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, random

I have 3 anchor blocks where I want 3 different random `background-colors` when I load the page. However only the first anchor is randomly changing `background-color`. Here is the HTML and jQuery code I use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready ( function () {
        var color = '#'; // hexadecimal starting symbol
        var letters = ['000000','FF0000','00FF00','0000FF','FFFF00','00FFFF','FF00FF','C0C0C0'];
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
        document.getElementById('kleur').style.background = color;
    });
</script>

<div class="content_block_list">
    <?php if( have_rows('content_block_list') ): ?>
        <ul>
            <?php while( have_rows('content_block_list') ): the_row(); 
                $content = get_sub_field('content');
                $button_link = get_sub_field('button_link'); ?>
                <li>
                     <div>
                        <?php if ($content == true){ ?>
                            <?php echo $content; ?>        
                        <?php } ?>
                        <?php if ($button_link == true){ ?>
                            <a id="kleur" class="more" href="<?php echo $button_link; ?>">LEES MEER</a>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                </li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>    
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

This code automatically generates 3 blocks with 'Read More' anchors, these anchors have a `background-color` which need to change randomly. Do I have to create a loop or something?

Here you can see that the first anchor does change background-color:

[image: First 'Read More' is changing background-color randomly]

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Give you're using `document.getElementById('kleur')` I assume that all the elements have the same `id` attribute. If so, this is your problem as `id` must be unique. Change this to a common class on all the elements instead. You will also need to loop through all the elements and apply a colour individually as at the moment you're giving them all the same colour.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The php loads all the blocks in so i only can give 1 ID or 1 class for the 3 blocks.

Comment: That's right - you can use a common class as I mentioned. I also added an answer with an example for you.

Answer (score 0):

All your `a` elements have the same `id`, which is invalid. `id` attributes *must* be unique. To fix this, change your HTML so the `a` elements all have a common class.

You will also need to loop through all those elements and apply a colour individually as at the moment you're giving them all the same colour. Try this:

```js
var colors = ['000000', 'FF0000', '00FF00', '0000FF', 'FFFF00', '00FFFF', 'FF00FF', 'C0C0C0'];

$('.kleur').each(function() {
  var color = '#' + colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  $(this).css('background-color', color);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content_block_list">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div>
        Foo bar
        <a class="kleur more" href="#>">LEES MEER</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        Foo bar
        <a class="kleur more" href="#>">LEES MEER</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        Foo bar
        <a class="kleur more" href="#>">LEES MEER</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to use different Id not same.

```
var colors = ['000000', 'FF0000', '00FF00', '0000FF', 'FFFF00', '00FFFF', 'FF00FF', 'C0C0C0'];

$('.more').each(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  var color = '#' + colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  $('#'+id).css('background-color', color);
});

<div class="content_block_list">
    <?php if( have_rows('content_block_list') ): ?>
        <ul>
            <?php 
                $i = 0;
                while( have_rows('content_block_list') ): the_row(); 
                $content = get_sub_field('content');
                $button_link = get_sub_field('button_link'); ?>
                <li>
                     <div>
                        <?php if ($content == true){ ?>
                            <?php echo $content; ?>        
                        <?php } ?>
                        <?php if ($button_link == true){ ?>
                            <a id="kleur_<?php echo $i; ?>" class="more" href="<?php echo $button_link; ?>">LEES MEER</a>
                        <?php $i++; } ?>
                    </div>
                </li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>    
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

use jQuery and loop through all elements with that id, if you dont have a chance to alter the ids for every element

```js
$(document).ready ( function () {
                var letters = ['000000','FF0000','00FF00','0000FF','FFFF00','00FFFF','FF00FF','C0C0C0']; //Set your colors here
                $("ul li").find("#kleur").each(function(){
                  color = letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
                  $(this).css("background-color","#"+color);
                });
              });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content_block_list">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div>
        Foo bar
        <a id="kleur" href="#>">LEES MEER</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        Foo bar
        <a id="kleur" href="#>">LEES MEER</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        Foo bar
        <a id="kleur" href="#>">LEES MEER</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

### EDIT

you can loop through the same ids if you use the `find()` function, but remember, a id SHOULD be unique

Comment: You can't 'loop through all elements with that id' - this is the issue the OP has right now. `id` attributes must be unique.

Comment: changed my answer... you are right, ID must be unique, but the good thing of HTML is, that it is very robust... so my edited abswer should work...

Comment: The logic now works, but it still relies on invalid HTML due to the repeated `#kleur`